# Task event listener JBPM 5.4

Tags: java, jbpm

I'm working with JBPM 5.4, I want to make a code that will be executed every time a human task is initiated. I searched for it  and I found that there is a class called task event listener

```
public interface TaskLifeCycleEventListener {

    //@TODO: add all the methods
    public void afterTaskActivatedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskClaimedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskSkippedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskStartedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskStoppedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskCompletedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskFailedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskAddedEvent(Task ti);
    public void afterTaskExitedEvent(Task ti);
}
```

That is the interface T could implement it but I don't know how to deploy it or register it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can register TaskEventListener with LocalTaskService, like as: 

`LocalTaskService localTaskService = new LocalTaskService(taskService);
taskService.addEventListener(new MyTaskEventListener(localTaskService, ksession));`

Comment: yes where to add that at my application or in the buisness process